# How do i translate the content into local languages in my wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, translation

As i am new to word press. i want to change the site content (Default English) into Local Languages. is this possible means tell the WordPress plugin which is used for this translation.
 Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

there is lot of translation plugin is available 
you may use Qtranslator [Qtranslate](http://wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate/) plugin to get

Comment: hmm can i translate english into tamil

Comment: Hi, you need the full website into tamil? if yes there is wordpress tamil version, so don't need to translate anything, you can also do it by Qtranslator

Comment: i checked it. but is this possible to change English into Tamil. because i need both Tamil and English language

Comment: the customer only have to change language

Comment: Hello, you can configure it by yourself

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can translate from english to tamil by using this Plugin [Translate plugin from tamil to english](http://wordpress.org/plugins/transposh-translation-filter-for-wordpress/screenshots/)